# Glide: Can't copy a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, image, android-image, android-glide, image-loading

I am using SubsamplingScaleImageView with Glide to load, cache and show images:

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView mImageView;

Glide.with(this)
.load(url)
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                mImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(
                    Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)));
        }
    });
```

It works but crashes sometimes with error `IllegalStateException: Can't copy a recycled bitmap` in `Bitmap.createBitmap`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your `Bitmap` gets recycled. To fix it, you can perform a check and then proceed with necessary action:

```
@Override
public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
    if (!resource.isRecycled()) {
        mImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: But with this checking image will not shown. Is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: You have to find out for what reason/under what condition/what results your `Bitmap` to get recycled. At this stage (in this callback) I cannot think of anything other than trying to load the image again.